# How do I put a series (such as) the result of a pandas groupby.apply(f) into a new column of the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, that I want to calculate statitics on (value_count, mode, mean, etc.) and then put the result in a new column.  My current solution is O(n**2) or so, and I'm sure there is likely a faster, obvious method that I'm overlooking.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 10)), 
                   columns = list('abcdefghij'))

df['result'] = 0

groups = df.groupby([df.i, df.j])
for g in groups:
    icol_eq = df.i == g[0][0]
    jcol_eq = df.j == g[0][1]
    i_and_j = icol_eq & jcol_eq
    df['result'][i_and_j] = len(g[1])
```

The above works, but is extremely slow for large dataframes.

I tried

```
df['result'] = df.groupby([df.i, df.j]).apply(len)
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Nor does

```
def f(g):
    g['result'] = len(g)
    return g

df.groupby([df.i, df.j]).apply(f)
```

Nor can I merge the resulting series of a df.groupby.apply(lambda x: len(x))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation):

```
In [98]:

df['result'] = df.groupby([df.i, df.j]).transform(len)
df
Out[98]:
    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  result
0   6  1  3  0  1  1  4  2  8  6       6
1   1  3  9  7  5  5  3  5  4  4       1
2   1  5  0  1  8  1  4  7  3  9       1
3   6  8  6  4  6  0  8  0  6  5       6
4   7  9  7  2  8  9  9  6  0  6       7
5   3  5  5  7  2  7  7  3  2  8       3
6   5  0  4  7  5  7  5  7  9  1       5
7   3  2  5  4  3  6  8  4  2  0       3
8   2  3  0  4  8  5  7  9  7  2       2
9   1  1  3  2  3  5  6  6  5  6       1
10  3  0  2  7  1  8  1  3  5  4       3
....
```

`transform` returns a Series with an index aligned to your original df so you can then add it as a column